# How to override Monolog core handler?

Tags: symfony, monolog

In symfony 2.5.9, I try to override SwiftMailerHandler of Monolog

```
class MySwiftMailerHandler extends SwiftMailerHandler
{
    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $message, $level = Logger::ERROR, $bubble = true)
    {
         $message->setSubject('Lorem ipsum : ' . $message->getSubject()) ;
         parent::__construct($mailer, $message, $level, $bubble);
    }
}
```

with service

```
<service id="my_custom_handler" class="XXXX\Monolog\Handler\MySwiftMailerHandler">
    <tag name="monolog.handler.swift"/> <!-- which tag to use ? -->
</service>
```

and config

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        mail:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      custom #before buffered
        custom:
            type: service
            id: my_custom_handler
        #buffered:
        #    type:    buffer
        #    handler: swift
        swift:
            type:       swift_mailer
            from_email: %monolog_from_email%
            to_email:   %monolog_to_email%
            subject:    'Error'
            level:      critical
```

But my handler has following error : "__construct() must be an instance of Swift_Mailer, none given..."

How to create my new handler service ? Bad config monolog ? Which tag to use ? How to do ?
Thanks!

Comment: When you declare your service, you are not passing any of the required dependencies. Advise you to check how the core code does it and read a bit more about dependency injections in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  All of the various handler classes are defined as parameters within `monolog.xml` inside of `MonologBundle`.  (`MonologExtension` seems to instantiate and configure these from within a big switch statement.)

To override `SwiftMailerHandler`, specify the class *parameter* like so:

`parameters:
    ...
    monolog.handler.swift_mailer.class: XXXX\Monolog\Handler\MySwiftMailerHandler`

No need to muck around with services, tags, etc.

I use this approach to override `SwiftMailerHandler::buildMessage()` and dynamically change the subject of the email message.

Comment: This is not working with new version of monolog/bundle (3.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class using a compiler pass:

> [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html): If you want to modify service definitions of another bundle, you can use a compiler pass to change the class of the service or to modify method calls.

```
// src/Kernel.php
namespace App;

// ...
+ use App\Service\YourService;
+ use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
+ use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
+     public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
+     {
+         $definition = $container->findDefinition('monolog.handler.swift');
+         $definition->setClass(YourService::class);
+     }
}
```